# d3-formatted Numbers Not Displaying Thousands-Separator

Tags: d3.js

I have this straightforward JavaScript function, which uses [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) to convert a string and currency code into a formatted number.

```
import * as d3Format from 'd3-format';
import d3 from 'd3';

export const toCurrency = (number, currencyCode) => {
    const formatDef = {
    "decimal": ".",
    "thousands": ",",
    "grouping": [3],
    "currency": [convertCodeToSymbol(currencyCode), ""]};
    const locale = d3Format.formatLocale(formatDef);
    return locale.format("($.2f")(number);
};

const convertCodeToSymbol = (currencyCode) => {
    const conversions = {
        "USD": "$",
        "EUR": "€",
        "GBP": "£"
    };
    return conversions[currencyCode] ? conversions[currencyCode] : currencyCode;
};
```

It works except for the thousands-separator, which isn't displaying. Given (1999, "USD") it's returning "$1999.00". I've double checked the docs, but both the thousands and grouping attribute look correct. I am trying to get "$1,999.00".

(Note, the import d3 line isn't necessary, but I included it just to make sure I wasn't missing part of the library. I have installed both d3 and d3-format with npm.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing the `thousands` property of the [locale definition](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatLocale) you only specify what the group separator should *look* like when it is requested for formatting. To actually group the formatted output, you need to include the comma (`,`) option  into the specifier string provided to [`locale.format(specifier)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format):

> The *comma* (,) option enables the use of a group separator, such as a comma for thousands.

For your code this means changing the specifier string to

```
return locale.format("($,.2f")(number);
```

should do the trick.

This working examples shows the difference:

```js
console.log(d3.format(".2f")(1999));   // 1999.00
console.log(d3.format(",.2f")(1999));  // 1,999.00
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```